# Передача аргументов между методами

Tags: c#

Как сделать так, что бы в методе `After10Sec` можно было менять значение label1?

```
namespace en
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = "123";
        }
        public static void After10Sec()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);                            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "123";
        After10Sec();
    }
    public static void After10Sec()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(); // создаём таймер
        timer.Tick += (s,e)=> // это обработчик того, что произойдёт после интервала
                      {
                           label1.Text="10 second have passed";
                           timer.Enabled = false; // выключаем таймер, если нужно срабатывание только раз   
                      }
        myTimer.Interval = 10000; // задаём интервал
        myTimer.Start(); // стартуем
    }
```